# KVM module not found by virtual machine manager

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kvm, kernel-module

On ubuntu when I launch the virtual machine manager I get a warning saying that KVM is not installed. I installed it from apt-get.

Ran modprobe and got:

```
$ modprobe -l | grep kvm
kernel/arch/x86/kvm/kvm.ko
kernel/arch/x86/kvm/kvm-intel.ko
kernel/arch/x86/kvm/kvm-amd.ko
```

I ran `modprobe -a` on all the above and did not get any results... The my current user is part of the libvirtd group.

Running on Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sudo insmod kvm-intel`

or simply

`sudo insmod kvm`

does that work?

Also check this:

First check if your CPU supports hardware virtualization - if this is the case, the command

`egrep '(vmx|svm)' --color=always /proc/cpuinfo`

should display something, e.g. like this:

root@server1:~# egrep '(vmx|svm)' --color=always /proc/cpuinfo
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush
mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt rdtscp lm 3dnowext 3dnow rep_good nopl extd_apicid
pni cx16 lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy 3dnowprefetch lbrv
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush
mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt rdtscp lm 3dnowext 3dnow rep_good nopl extd_apicid
pni cx16 lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy 3dnowprefetch lbrv
root@server1:~#

If nothing is displayed, then your processor doesn't support hardware virtualization, and you must stop here.

Comment: sorry insmod is the command.

Comment: fixed in the answer per the suggestion.

Comment: Ran the egrep got the same result. So my CPU is compatible (its an Intel i5) so that is good.

The result: `root@host:~# insmod kvm
insmod: can't read 'kvm': No such file or directory`

Comment: Here is a complete guide for KVM on ubuntu 12.04 on howto forge. http://www.howtoforge.com/virtualization-with-kvm-on-ubuntu-12.04-lts

Comment: make sure you have mvm.ko and kvm-intel.ko in the correct place for kernel modules.

Comment: also make sure you have the VT features enabled in BIOS.

Comment: Issue was I forgot to check the BIOS. Enabled it and it worked. Thanks.